# What class are these Federation ships?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In DS9: Season 6, Episode 5: Favor the Bold.

What are these small ships which are moving in the foreground when the fleet departs for DS9?

[image]

And I believe again here:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are indeed listed as Peregrine Class Fighters. It was the name given and being the only seen ships in canon beside the large Maquis raider. A lot of people play with an image and add it onto a "fanpost". Technical design list them as Peregrine Class as well. http://www.trekbbs.com/showthread.php?t=83332 a posted Lcar image and in all data banks of Lcar! The name may be incorrect that @Thaddeus listed, but the image is Peregrine! http://www.kitsune.addr.com/SF-Conversions/Rifts-Trek-Ships/Federation_Peregrine_Warp_Fighter.htm.. Also, please note the Marquis were Ex-Federation officers and citizens fighting against the Federation and Cardassian due to reshaping of the DMZ. His images are of the episode where they used them as Freedom fighters. However, that is not their official name.

Answer (score 24):

From Memory Alpha's article on the [Freedom Attack Fighter](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Federation_attack_fighter):

> [image: Freedom attack fighter]
>
> The Federation attack fighter was a type of starship employed by
>   Starfleet as an attack fighter during the Dominion War. (DS9:
>   "Sacrifice of Angels")
>
> **History**
>
> The Maquis appropriated several of these ships and used them as attack
>   fighters during their insurrection against the Cardassian Union. Prior
>   to 2370 these ships were civilian Federation support couriers not used
>   by Starfleet.
>
> **Fighters attacking the Dominion Fleet during Operation Return**
>
> Large numbers of these ships were used by Starfleet in the Dominion
>   War. During Operation Return, eight successive waves of fighters were
>   sent to attack the Cardassian ships of a Dominion fleet, hoping to
>   provoke them into breaking formation and creating an opening for the
>   Federation fleet. (DS9: "Sacrifice of Angels")

---

[2]: Memory Alpha: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Federation_attack_fighter

Answer (score -2):

They are Peregrine Class Fighters 
 http://www.ditl.org/ship-page.php?ClassID=fedperegrine&ListID=Ships&ListOption=fed

Comment: Can you expand on this answer, and add a picture of the ship? Why do you think this is a better fit that Thaddeus' answer?

Comment: This is a link-only answer and not of any use.

Answer (score -4):

I'm a HUGE Star Trek Fan and play A LOT of Star Trek games and I can tell you that those are known as a Paragrine Fighters!

Comment: Assuming you're referring to Peregrine-Class fighters, they're (supposedly) the class that @thaddeus' answer already refers to: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Peregrine_class. The Peregrine class is mentioned but never seen in the show : http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Federation_attack_fighter#Apocrypha